# Processing bad character in csv

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have a program which read csv file of default format with double quotes: "A", "B", "C" by default. However, the assumption is that user may submit any bad character in csv. such as "A"", "B", "C" or A, B, C" or "A',"B",""C or A, B, C. Above is just some sample and it may have endless possibility. The key is to append empty column if there is less than n column in csv and remove extra column in csv. There maybe 10000 or more records and all of the rows in csv must be read and insert into a list. Note that the csv file cannot be rejected or throw exception due to invalid characters. How could it be done? I can't seem to find a common pattern for it.

Comment: Where does that CSV come from? Why isn’t it properly encoded? There is a very simple rule about what happens with quotation marks in the content when the whole cell value is enquoted.

Comment: @poke the csv file came from the client. although we do provide format for the client, but we are being instructed to provide a solution to deal with situation whereby customer intentionally provide failure value as above. And we are required to process all rows.

Comment: Then you will need to create your own CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Regex to extract only alphanumeric characters?

```
string cleanedStr = Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

A more complete code will be something like this

```
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(YourCSVFilePath))
        {
            string[] strArr = line.Split(',');

            foreach (string str in strArr)
            {
                string cleanedStr = Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
                //Do your stuff with the cleanedStr here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not a programmatic one but it can help for a one/few time(s) task(s). I thought of leaving it here in case it might help.

This is a simple and very nice tool to work with `CSV` files: http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/